# Getting 404 not found on fonts

Tags: css, tomcat, fonts, http-status-code-404, font-face

http://[insert ip address here]/cabinet/fonts/Cabin-Regular.ttf

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Everything is set up correctly, the font works on my machine because it finds the Cabin font installed on my machine, after failing to find it on the server. However, I can't figure out how to get the error message to go away on the remote deployment.

Any thoughts on why a font, which is in a folder in the web server, would not be accessible?

```
| ip root
| | cabinet
| | | fonts<--fonts installed under this folder using Paul Irish recommended font-face    rules
| | | css<--css file pointing to the font-face is here
```

Comment: I had this error on my local machine and it was caused by the webserver not knowing which mimetype to use. Please answer to Mike Christensen question.

Comment: tomcat I believe is the answer to your question...

Answer (score 0):

The answer has nothing to do with fonts. The git -a command on commit was telling me in terminal that it was adding the files, but the files were not uploading to git for whatever reason. Once we checked the github web page we could see they were not there, and forced them up using eclipse instead of terminal. Odd.